# How to get each key of an object differently then push it into a new object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of object contain whole data of form.But i need to send that data differenty to the backend.all the object should br differently fetch then push it to another object as below.The data that i am getting is:

```
[
    {
        "messageType": "test",
        "eligibleUsers": "test2",
        "rules": [
            {
                "ruleId": "qwer",
                "value": "qwert"
            },
            {
                "ruleId": "testing",
                "value": "testing"
            },
            {
                "ruleId": "newtest",
                "value": "newtesting"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "messageType": "add",
        "eligibleUsers": "newadd",
        "rules": [
            {
                "ruleId": "qaz",
                "value": "qaz"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "messageType": "neww",
        "eligibleUsers": "add",
        "rules": [
            {
                "ruleId": "data",
                "value": "data1"
            },
            {
                "ruleId": "data2",
                "value": "dat3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But i want the data to be like this:

```
{
        "questions": [
            {
                "id": null,
                "ques": "test",
                "type": "dropdown",
                "message_user_type": "self",
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "rule": "qwer"
                    },
                    {
                        "rule": "testing"
                    },
                    {
                        "rule": "newtest"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": null,
                "ques": "test2",
                "type": "dropdown",
                "message_user_type": "emp",
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "rule": "qwert"
                    },
                    {
                        "rule": "testing"
                    },
                    {
                        "rule": "newtesting"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ques": "add",
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "rule": "qaz"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ques": "newadd",
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "rule": "qaz"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ques": "neww",
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "rule": "data"
                    },
                    {
                        "rule": "data2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ques": "add",
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "rule": "data"
                    },
                    {
                        "rule": "data2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thank you in advance

Comment: I can't find a pattern. How are things like `"dropdown"` or `message_user_type` computed?

Comment: These things can be ignore, but this structure is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get you started on this. You want to use `Array.map` like so:

```js
const data = [
  {
      "messageType": "test",
        "eligibleUsers": "test2",
        "rules": [
          {
              "ruleId": "qwer",
                "value": "qwert"
            },
            {
              "ruleId": "testing",
                "value": "testing"
            },
            {
              "ruleId": "newtest",
                "value": "newtesting"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
      "messageType": "add",
        "eligibleUsers": "newadd",
        "rules": [
            {
                "ruleId": "qaz",
                "value": "qaz"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "messageType": "neww",
        "eligibleUsers": "add",
        "rules": [
            {
                "ruleId": "data",
                "value": "data1"
            },
            {
                "ruleId": "data2",
                "value": "dat3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
  
const questions = data.map(obj => {
  return {
    "id": null,
    "ques": null,
    "type": null,
    "message_user_type": null,
    "rules": obj.rules.map(rule => ({ rule: rule.ruleId }))
  }
})

const result = { questions }

console.log(result)
```

With `Array.map` the result array will have the same length as the initial array. If you want something more complex you might want to consider `Array.reduce`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but how can i vice-versa, if i want same that i was getting initially, can you please help me with that

Comment: just use Array.map or Array.reduce again to convert it back